# ¿Como usar una sentencia Case en Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas una es la de detalle de producto y la otra es la de producto, el problema radica en que yo quiero hacer un `left join` para traerme los datos que estén relacionados en ambas tablas, el atributo que debe de relacionarse es el de "Numero de Producto", ese debe ser el mismo en ambas tablas, pero aparte quiero traerme el resto de los registros solo que cuando la relación sea igual me mande que si existe una relación y cuando no solo me marque que no hay relación en un atributo aparte, pero no lo hago con `inner join` porque ahí solo me traerá los que coinciden y lo que yo requiero es que me traiga todos pero me marque si hay o no relación en cada registro de la tabla.

Aqui esta el código de mi consulta actual

```
 SELECT
    ct.sNumeroProducto as Producto, detalle.sProducto as Detalle
    case ct.sNumeroProducto  when ct.sNumeroProducto=detalle.sProducto then 'Todos'  when ct.sNumeroProducto!=detalle.sProducto then 'En vigor'
    FROM ct_producto ct  left join  ct_producto_detalle detalle on detalle.sProducto=ct.sNumeroProducto
```

El error es el siguiente

```
11:54:08 Kernel error: Error( 1064 ) 42000: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case ct.sNumeroProducto  when ct.sNumeroProducto=detalle.sProducto then 'Todos' ' at line 3"
```

Nota: No quiero almacenarlo de manera permanente en la BD, sino que en una columna virtual solamente mostrarlo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuviste un error al declarar el query, así como una coma faltante.

```
SELECT 
    ct.sNumeroProducto AS Producto,
    detalle.sProducto AS Detalle,
    CASE
        WHEN ct.sNumeroProducto = detalle.sProducto THEN 'Todos'
        WHEN ct.sNumeroProducto != detalle.sProducto THEN 'En vigor'
    END as Estado
FROM
    ct_producto ct
        LEFT JOIN
    ct_producto_detalle detalle ON (detalle.sProducto = ct.sNumeroProducto)
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tenias mal estructurado la sentencia case.

Prueba con el siguiente código:

```
    SELECT
        ct.sNumeroProducto as Producto, 
        detalle.sProducto as Detalle
        case  
           when ct.sNumeroProducto=detalle.sProducto then 'Todos'  
           when ct.sNumeroProducto!=detalle.sProducto then 'En vigor'
        end case
    FROM ct_producto ct  
         left join  ct_producto_detalle detalle 
         on detalle.sProducto = ct.sNumeroProducto
```

según la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) de MySql